# Chrome bookmark duplicate removal extension

Tags: chrome, bookmark

I have 3 devices, one tablet, one phone and one desktop computer. I had about 1500 websites bookmarked in my desktop. I went to Google Chrome settings in my laptop and synchronised the bookmarks.

Some how I have 4 copies of each website with total of 6000 websites in bookmark. Every time I disconnect my Google account from Chrome and login back, it synchronise a new set of bookmarks.

Doesnt anyone know any software that can eliminate this problem? I have tried like 10 extension to delete duplicate bookmarks but none of them works.

The bookmarks are stored in different folders, for example imported, imported2, imported3

Comment: Could you list the extensions you have tried and explain what didn't work with each one?